# Dotted lines and References Heading in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following latex master file of my thesis:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,left=1.5in,
right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1.33in, footskip=0.33in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename
    \ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter }
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\widthof{\large\textbf{Chapter 1}}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\overfullrule=5pt
\hfuzz=20pt
\vfuzz=20pt
\hbadness=10000
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
    \markright {\thesection.\ #1}}
\parindent0pt
\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
    {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
\setlinespacing{1.5}
\newtheorem*{theorem-non}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\medskip\par\noindent{\bf Proof\;}}%
{\hspace{\fill}$\Box$\medskip\par}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\numberwithin{lemma}{chapter}
\numberwithin{corollary}{chapter}
\numberwithin{example}{chapter}
\numberwithin{remark}{chapter}
\numberwithin{definition}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\hyphenpenalty 50
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} \setlinespacing{1.5}
%\input{Acknowledgement}
\newpage
\input{mytitle.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{chap1.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap2.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap3.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap4.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap5.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap6.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap7.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap8.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{bib.tex}
\end{document}
```

My title file has the following commands:

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
```

The bibliography is written manually as:

```
\newpage
\begin{center}
\Large{\textbf{References}}
\end{center}
%\newpage
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
%\renewcommand\bibname{References}


\begin{thebibliography} {99}
\bibitem{Ross-2012} Ross, B. (1977).
The development of fractional calculus 1695–1900.
\emph{Historia Mathematica}. 4(1), 75--89. \end{thebibliography}
```

I would like to have a dotted line between the chapter title, which is written in bold, and its respective page number in the thesis. The same dotted line should be present for other chapters as well.

As for the "References" section, it should not be treated as a chapter, but it should still appear in the table of contents. Additionally, there should be a dotted line between the heading "References" and its corresponding page number.